# How to add a listener to a button - not from activity class

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I have a button set in XML like so:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/playervicesbutton" />
```

It's part of a simple alert dialogue which display an error message (I used this rather than a simple '.setNeutralButton' because I have more control over it's appearance this way).

I'm having a lot of problems simply dismissing the dialogue when the button is pressed.

the problem is that I am not invoking this from my activity class, so if I use the following in XML:

```
android:onClck="dismissDialog" />
```

the dismissDialog(View myView) method has to be in my main Activity class correct? And my main Activity class does not have visibility of this dialogue as it's created, held and called from a different class.

Again, I can't use this either:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dismissButton);
```

Because my class doesn't have access to findByView

So how can I dismiss this dialogue using a button defined in XML?

(I've looked all over, but all examples assume this button is created in, and called from the main activity class - my code currently has 55 classes and a lot of stuff happens away from / detached from the activity class.

I'm not too familiar with dialogues and XML - my code is (apart from this one alertDialog) purely OpenGL - help appreciated

Comment: How do you inflate the xml? Can you provide more details on your Java classes? It seems this is only a problem of passing the right object reference to the right place.